# /bin/sh: [./Filename]: not found

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates icu-libs

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

ENV TZ=America/Chicago
#This will update the image to avoid security issues.
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add bash
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Filename/Filename.csproj", "Filename/"]


RUN dotnet restore "Filename/Filename.csproj" --configfile NuGet.Config 
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Filename"
RUN dotnet build "Filename.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Filename.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish  --runtime alpine-x64 --self-contained true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Filename.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT [./"Filename"]
```

I have a console application with Dotnet 6.0.  My dockerfile script built successfully however, it failed at runtime when deploying to the server with Error : /bin/sh: [./Filename]: not found

my image ran fine when it's dotnetcore 3.1 and with script runtime-deps:3.1-alpine AS base.
So why does it require /bin/sh: when it's in dotnet 6.0.  How do you fix this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try what you suggested but what is the command for adding bin\sh?

Comment: /bin/sh is already part of Alpine.

Comment: Well then that is not working.  I am wondering if these two tags links below are current not supported.  
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-alpine as base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build

However, I tried to use what other suggested and they are not working with error : ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine-amd64

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your build script as above using a simple console application, and it seems that the issue is that you incorrectly wrote `[./"Filename"]` rather than `["./Filename"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the entrypoint at the end of your dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./Filename"]
```

Comment: Vote to close the question as a typo. There's a specific close vote reason for it because typos are not useful to future readers.

Answer (score -1):

Updated your dockerfile you can use it, It will resolve the issue..!!!

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates icu-libs

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

ENV TZ=America/Chicago
#This will update the image to avoid security issues.
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add bash
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Filename/Filename.csproj", "Filename/"]


RUN dotnet restore "Filename/Filename.csproj" --configfile NuGet.Config 
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Filename"
RUN dotnet build "Filename.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Filename.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish  --runtime alpine-x64 --self-contained true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE portnumber
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:portnumber
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Filename.dll"]
```

Comment: Is dotnet included in the Alpine base image? Also, the publish command used doesn't generate a .dll file.

Comment: I found the issue after I ran an inspection on the image, I noticed that the Entrypoint it created for Dotnet 6.0 is different than dotnetcore 3.1.  Entrypoint = null
Where Dotnet 6.0 
"Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "[./\"Filename\"]"
So, I changed ENTRYPOINT ["./Filename"] intead of ENTRYPOINT [./"Filename"] and it works.
I posted it here so it might help anyone with the same issue later.

Thank you for all of your help with this matter.

Comment: Yes dotnet include Alpine, Worked applied the same in my current project Docker file and it is working fine as well as creating light weight image...!!!